# Nginx configuration for docker wordpress:php8.0-fpm-alpine

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, wordpress

My objective is to create a server block in a host Nginx configuration that serves as a fastcgi frontend for a wordpress php docker container.

That is to say, the nginx server is not in a container, and I do not want it to be in a container. I also don't really care if the wordpress site's static files are somehow served directly by Nginx -- if it's easier to have the container serve them then that is what I would like to do.

I have a docker container running with the wordpress:php8.0-fpm-alpine image. So far, I've only tried the Nginx-provided server block:

```
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name domain.tld;
        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/wordpress;
        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

As well as the linked suggested example: https://gist.github.com/md5/d9206eacb5a0ff5d6be0#file-wordpress-fpm-conf

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name localhost; 
  root /var/www/html; 

  index index.php; 

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { 
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
      return 404;
    }

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_pass   fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php; 
  } 
}
```

In both examples I have substituted my domain and the php server hostname/socket as needed. However, both clearly use direct access to the wordpress static files. How would I go about forwarding those requests too? And does that solve the problem? I don't actually know that the fpm-alpine image serves its static content, but I assume it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP-FPM only serves the PHP content. Most example give a `-v` flag to map a path/volume on the host to a path within the docker container

The first question is "Does the docker container respond to non CGI requests" which comes back to "I also don't really care if the wordpress site's static files are somehow served directly by Nginx"

Is the docker contaner running on the nginx host or a remote one?
If it's local then changing `servername` and `root` in the second example is the way to go.
If the content is on a remote server then you need to use something like NFS to share the content with the Nginx server.
There are other ways but they are the simplest

EDIT 1

> I changed the servername and root, and was able to access the files. I'm a bit concerned though if I'm doing that right.

That is correct

> is there a way to ensure that using a newer revision of the docker image always overwrites the volume?

Docker will use the images that are on the host in question. You don't give any detail there, but generally you'll need to do `docker stop <name>` && `docker pull <new image>` && `docker run <new image>`  Note the image may be `latest` or some other rolling tag.

EDIT2 (from comments Re: Will the volumes be overridden)

That comes into how you're running. Everything not covered by the `-v` option will be lost. IIRC wordpress has a `wp-content`, possibly a `wp-includes` folder and sql config. So I'd expect 2 `-v` options to map local folders into the container as well as well as a bunch of  `-e` or a `--env-file`.

Everything not covered by those volumes and environment would be replaced with a new container

Comment: The container is running on the nginx host! I changed the servername and root, and was able to access the files. I'm a bit concerned though if I'm doing that right -- is there a way to ensure that using a newer revision of the docker image always overwrites the volume?

Comment: As a second followup, it turns out that I'm not successfully using FPM with this arrangement. I'll debug it some more and give you the solve, but I'd like help with at least the first followup since it's in scope of the question still. Let me know what other info you need.

Comment: Re: Docker will use the images that are on the host in question -- understood, the question is whether stop -> pull -> run will overwrite the volume if the same volume is attached to the new image, or if the volume should be discarded and an identically-named volume created.